# User registration on Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

```
                    User registration:
```

One user registration and there are two types:
1) Teacher 
2) Student 
when user come in user registration form and put mandatory information, And also there drop down list Teacher and Student, Choose one option.
And open their related fields when choosing second option first option is hidden and second will appear on the screen.
And then register.

Comment: You can have look at https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/user-management/ , I have developed JoomProfile, which can work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using two different templates for registration. One is for Teacher and one is for student. And override the registration on your templates. That is simple and you'll have full control over the two different sections.